# Could someone add an apologetics tag?

Tags: support, tags

I think that questions related to defending the faith are important and I don't have the rep to created tags.

Would this be consider a feature request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you do!

Steve, rep restrictions are relaxed significantly in a private beta. You only need 1 rep to create a tag. Go ahead and create [apologetics](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apologetics). Typically tags are not created instead they are just added to a question. If you for some reason cannot add a tag to a question just leave a comment or flag your question in order to have the tag added.

Comment: Hmm. That's strange, I can edit in a new tag but I can't make a new one when asking a question. Is this intended?

Comment: I just added one and it was fine. All you have to do it type the word into the tag bar.

Comment: Hmm maybe it is a problem with the mobile site.

Comment: very possibly. You might switch this to a bug report rather than a feature request and specify you are using the mobile version. Or it may be served as a seperate meta q

Comment: I'll check to see if it is a stack exchange bug or a Christainity se site bug.